# ggpairs: Remove y axis label for only one plot

Tags: r, label, ggpairs

Helllo,
I have made a correlation plot with ggpairs but I would like to remove the y axis labels in the first plot and then have a common range for the y axis for all the other plots (0 -1).
The code I used is:

```
ggpairs(predMatrixVal,labeller = "label_parsed", axisLabels = "none")
```

And the plot is:
[image]

Do you have any idea how to do this?